# My extension's "Local Extension Settings" Logfile gets too big

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote the chrome extension View Later: [click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-later-save-links-in/hnolaplfoobcmgfmjphkmbjolinelpkb)

A user reported, that there is a log file that gets way too big (his was around 3.8GB) that is located at `C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Extension Settings\hnolaplfoobcmgfmjphkmbjolinelpkb`.

I immediately checked at my machine and it was big as well (~300mb). I do not know what is causing this. I use the `chrome.storage` heavily in my extension (all url's are saved there) but I do not know how this can get so big, as the limit is 512 entries to my knowledge.

Anyone got clues on this?
Thanks!

Comment: "the limit is 512 entries to my knowledge" What limit?

Comment: What's inside this log file?

Comment: the limit I'm talking about is the chrome.storage limit. Inside the log file is some encoded stuff, but some things I can read which is data i stored in the storage

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a log of all storage events.

No idea why Chrome keeps it, and I don't think you can do anything to clean it.

It sounds like a bug [worth reporting](https://crbug.com/new) (why is this logging on, and what's the cutoff?).

Comment: Thanks i made a bug report [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578427)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you get favicons for saved URLs via `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=` service, convert them into Base64, and store in Local Storage. It might cause the problem.

Instead, you may try not to save them, but load `http://www.google.com/s2/favicons` every time user opens the Popup.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the documentation states that the local storage is limited to 512 entries or 5MB, I doubt it  has to do with that

Comment: @kentobi Only the `sync` storage is limited to 512 entries, and you can remove 5MB limit on `local` storage.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

if the log file is a result of chrome.storage.

it looks like a bug. chrome.stoage.{local, sync} has a limit of quota.

Thank you for the bug reporting btw.